# Android: how to get default camera settings of builtin camera application

Tags: java, android, camera, settings, default

I have seen lots of tutorial and information but i could not find any single place how to use the default settings of the existing camera application into any other customized camera application. I have seen the sharpness of the image and its focus is very fine in the built-in camera application. Now i am creating my own application with my customized features but i am still unable to make it sharp and non-blurry... I dont want to use Intent technique of the camera because i have to do some image processing afterward.

I have used zooming but strangely zoom is  not properly working ...like it works in built-in camera application

here is my surface change code

```
   public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h)
{
    Log.e(TAG, "surfaceChanged");

    // XXX stopPreview() will crash if preview is not running
    if (mPreviewRunning) {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
    }


     Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
     List<Camera.Size> sizes = params.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
     mFrameWidth =  w;
     mFrameHeight = h;

     // selecting optimal camera preview size
     {
         double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
         for (Camera.Size size : sizes) 
         {
             if (Math.abs(size.height - h) < minDiff) 
             {
                 mFrameWidth = size.width;
                 mFrameHeight = size.height;
                 minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - h);
             }
         }
     }

    try 
    {

        //params.set("rotation", 180);
        //params.set("orientation", "landscape");
        //params.set("auto", "WHITE_BALANCE_AUTO");//WHITE_BALANCE_AUTO 




        Display display = ((WindowManager)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();

        if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_0)
        {
            params.setPreviewSize(mFrameHeight, mFrameWidth);                           
            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        }

        if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_90)
        {
            params.setPreviewSize(mFrameWidth, mFrameHeight);                           
        }

        if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_180)
        {
            params.setPreviewSize(mFrameHeight, mFrameWidth);               
        }

        if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_270)
        {
            params.setPreviewSize(mFrameWidth, mFrameHeight);
            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(180);
        }

        if(params.isZoomSupported())
        {

            Log.e(TAG, params.getZoom()+"surfaceChanged camer zoom"+params.getMinExposureCompensation());
            params.setZoom(params.getMaxZoom());
            params.setExposureCompensation(1);
                  //    params.setColorEffect("none");
            params.setWhiteBalance(params.WHITE_BALANCE_AUTO);
            params.setFocusMode(params.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
            params.setSceneMode(params.SCENE_MODE_ACTION);

        }

        params.set("auto", "FOCUS_MODE_AUTO");

        params.setPreviewSize(mFrameWidth,mFrameHeight);
        mCamera.setParameters(params);

        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mCamera.startPreview();
    mPreviewRunning = true;
}
```

Kindly let me know how to make the camera preview exactly same as the built in application one.

Comment: Have you looked at the Android Camera Application code.  You can pull it for the minimum version of the OS you will support and use it as a base.  Keep in mind that every OS upgrade add's capabilities, and the mfg of your device probably has support for features that may or may not exist on other devices.

Answer (score 2):

You mean a fullscreen camera preview?

I use this code:

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); //no title
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); //no status bar, etc
```

and this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
    addContentView(overlay, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.preview)).addView(preview);
```

the first snippet sets the app to fullscreen and hide title and status bar.
the second snipppet adds my overlay (extended View) to the main layout.

Here my xml and java code:
main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/preview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Overlay.java:

```
class Overlay extends View {
    String text = "";
    String textBearing = "Bearing: ";

    public Overlay(Context context) {
            super(context);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint.setTextSize(16);
        canvas.drawText(text, 20, 20, paint);
        canvas.drawText(textBearing, 20, 50, paint);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

And my activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); //no title
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); //fullscreen
    overlay = new Overlay(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    addContentView(overlay, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    camera = getCameraInstance(); //camera.open();
    preview = new Preview(this, camera);
    ((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.preview)).addView(preview);
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Does your code account for the space that the bars were taking up? I had a similar solution but I had to get the height of the bars and add it as padding.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem with you. After reading the source code of the builtin camera app, and comparing the focus processing of builtin camera and my own camera, I realized the problem is on autofocus.

So try this:

```
    mCamera.autoFocus(new Camera.AutoFocusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
            mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
        }
    });
```

which makes the result image as sharp as builtin camera.
The documents is [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#autoFocus(android.hardware.Camera.AutoFocusCallback)).